# Change Eclipse Dynamic Variable to build a single c++ class

Tags: c++, eclipse, build, dynamic-variables

I would like to change the dynamic variable ${selected_resource_loc} such that I get rid of the extension (and can add another one).

The purpose is to build the current selected file, but therefore I don't need the .cc-file in my command but the .o-file with the same name.

Detailed description:
I have a customized make command (lets say `make`) and would like to execute `make selectedFileName.o`, where the current selected file in eclipse is selectedFileName.cc. (I put the command as build command in project properties -> C/C++ Build.) With variable `${selected_resource_loc}` in behaviour tab I get `make selectedFileName.cc`.

Comment: can you give an example of what you are trying to do? I can't figure out if it's something to do with eclipse project properties or with your code....

Comment: It has nothing to do with my code. See detailed explanation in question part.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by writing a skript where I modify the `${selected_resource_loc}` and included it via external tools in eclipse.